# docker-compose cache webpack

Tags: docker, webpack, caching, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile, that looks like this:

```
FROM node:latest as assets
WORKDIR /app/
COPY files/assets/ /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest
[...]
COPY --from=assets /app/dist/ /app/static/
[...]
```

A docker-compose file similar to this:

```yaml
version: "3.5"
services:
  app:
    build: .
```

And a package.json that comes down to this:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "webpack": "^5.76.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    }
}
```

The problem is, that webpack needs a long time (~30s) to build the assets, even in dev mode, which is really annoying when developing. I want to avoid running the dev-server, because i want to keep the build process in a separate container.

Webpack has an [option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#cachetype) for file system cache, which speeds up the compilation, so i want to make use of it. But docker doesn't seem to allow mounting volumes during build time, so i don't know how to realize that.

Running webpack outside of docker is not an option, because that would mean that every host would need to have node and npm installed. It is totally fine though to keep the cache (and maybe even node_modules) in a folder somewhere.

Is there any solution to this issue?